# Is there a way to get all tags that have a class attribute in python using scrapy?

Tags: python, html, scrapy

Lets say I have an html page that has many different attributes that all have the same class:

```
<a href = "www.example1.com" class = "example-class" Example Text 1 />
<a href = "www.example2.com" class = "example-class" Example Text 2 />
<a href = "www.example3.com" class = "example-class" Example Text 3 />
```

Is it possible to get all the text for all the text that has the class "example-class"? So in this case, Example Text 1, Example Text 2, and Example Text 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with:

```
def parse(self, response):
    texts = response.css('a.example-class::text').getall()
    for text in texts:
        print(text)
```

**Css selector in scrapy**

`a.example-class::text` will target `<a>` elements that have the class `example-class` and `::text` is a special selector in scrapy that will extract the text-content of those selectors.

However, you wrote that your elements look like:

```
<a href = "www.example1.com" class = "example-class" Example Text 1 />
```

It looks a bit weird, normally links should look like this:

```
<a href = "www.example1.com" class = "example-class">Example Text 1</a>
```

If you wrote them wrong the scrapy code above should work.